# How does the Linux kernel create the /proc/$pid/maps file?

Tags: c, linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel, system-calls

I am doing some memory introspection and it requires me to know how proc/$pid/maps is created. I'm a bit confused by the code found in http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/base.c on line 2750 I notice that there is a definition in this struct for maps but I want to know for each pid_entry which kernel function creates the maps file. A link to the kernel module or block of code is sufficient.

Comment: /proc is a virtual file system. The files aren't backed by physical storage and their content is generated as you read it. In that sense, the files are never "created".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did something weird with the link.

Clicking through few definitions reveals the file is generated on demand here:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/bcf876870b95592b52519ed4aafcf9d95999bc9c/fs/proc/task_mmu.c#L271

(at least for the common mmu case)

the usual question: why are you asking?

Comment: I want to output the same data seen in a processes map file in /proc/$pid/maps using only memory introspection.